# PHP: get_headers issue with bitly AND long urls with spaces

Tags: php, url

I have a long URL:

```
$url='http://www.likecool.com/Car/Motorcycle/BMW%20Urban%20Racer%20Concept%20Motorcycle/BMW-Urban-Racer-Concept-Motorcycle.jpg';
```

I create a short one:

```
$url='http://goo.gl/oZ04P8';     
$url='http://bit.ly/1CzOQbf';
```

I run `$headers = get_headers($url); print_r($headers);`

**SCENARIO:**

`get_headers` works *correctly* for goo.gl short code but *incorrectly* for BITLY shortcode (404).

The difference is that BITLY shows up with *spaces* in the long url (bad) and GOOGL %20 (good).

When `get_headers` redirects the (long) url (with spaces) it FAILS.

I see no obvious way to fix this - am I missing something?

TWO OPTIONS 
- change the way BITLY encodes `?` (I force %20 formatting in long url)
- change the way `get_headers` encodes its URLs

Comment: you are run URL in browser first

Answer (score 1):

You could replace the content of the header by yourself once you received it :

```
$url = 'http://bit.ly/1CzOQbf';
$headers = get_headers($url, 1);
$headers['Location'] = str_replace(' ', '%20', $headers['Location']);
print_r($headers);
```

Output :

```
[Location]=>http://www.likecool.com/Car/Motorcycle/BMW%20Urban%20Racer%20Concept%20Motorcycle/BMW-Urban-Racer-Concept-Motorcycle-1.jpg
```

I added the second parameter of `get_headers` so it names the keys of the returned array, that way it's clearer to use / modify. It is obviously not needed at all.

Comment: This was the suggestions I was going to make - It seems a bit clunky, but obviously if there isn't consistency in url encoding it probably does the job well enough.